How to keep updated information in a RAG system?
I have created a RAG system with documents I have (saved in chunks). I was wondering how to keep updated information in responses.
For example, I have news articles about one subject. Those articles may add new information over time but also can correct outdated information in past documents.
I was thinking about a "graph" where my retrieved document is brought to my system with all other more recent documents associated. Then I might use LLM with all the documents brought and try to extract the most recent not outdated information.
Is there any technology that treats this problem ?
Thank you

Your idea of using a graph structure with temporal awareness is indeed a valid approach. This can be implemented using graph databases like Neo4j or Amazon Neptune.
